# How function is called without parameters?

Tags: scala, function, apache-spark, higher-order-functions

I'm trying to understand below code snippet

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

seq : Seq[String] = Seq("A","B")
val op:Seq[Column] = seq.map(col)
```

my understanding is `map` is function from trait `TraversableLike` and `Seq[String]` is able to call this map `function` because it has been implemented by Seq class somewhere. I hope upto here is correct.

Now `col` is function in trait `functions` and takes a parameter like `col(colName: Strig)` as per the documentation.

So how come its working just taking `col` function as parameter but not its respective parameter ?

can anyone please explain how its working behind the scenes ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> So how come its working just taking col function as parameter but not its respective parameter ?

The call to `seq.map(col)` only takes a function as an argument because `map` will pass each individual element contained in `seq` to that function (`col`).  Let's walk through the code at a high level to break down what is going on:

1. `seq` is defined as a `Seq[String]` containing two strings: "A" and "B"
2. `seq.map(col)` is called to convert each of the strings contained in `seq` to a `Column` instance. `map` iterates through the contents of `seq` and does the following:

   - It sees "A" and calls `col("A")` to produce the first `Column` value
   - It sees "B" and calls `col("B")` to produce the second `Column` value
   - It builds a new `Seq[Column]` containing all of the `Column` values generated in the previous steps, and returns it
3. The result of `seq.map(col)` is stored in the variable `op`

Answer (score 0):

From the Scaladocs:

`map`

> Builds a new sequence by applying a function to all elements of this sequence.

It has this function signature:

> ```scala
> def map[B](f: (A) => B): Seq[B]
> ```

Where:

`A` is the input type of the function `f`

`B` is "the element type of the returned sequence."

`f` is "the function to apply to each element."

and `returns` "a new sequence resulting from applying the given function `f` to each element of this sequence and collecting the results."

In this case, you are applying each element in the sequence as an argument to the function `col`, which expects a `String` as a parameter. `col` returns a `Column`, thus you have mapped your `Seq` of `String`s to a `Seq` of `Column`s.

I highly recommend checking out the official Scala documentation:

[`Seq.map`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/collection/Seq.html#:%7E:text=%EE%85%97-,def,(f%3A%20(A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%3A%20Seq%5BB%5D,-Builds%20a%20new)

Also from the docs, `map`s definition classes are [IterableOps](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/collection/IterableOps.html#:%7E:text=%EE%85%97-,def,(f%3A%20(A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%3A%20CC%5BB%5D,-Builds%20a%20new) → [abstract in] [IterableOnceOps](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.4/scala/collection/IterableOnceOps.html#:%7E:text=%EE%85%97-,abstract%20def,(f%3A%20(A)%20%3D%3E%20B)%3A%20CC%5BB%5D,-Builds%20a%20new)